# Error prompt position issue with validationengine plugin (Position Absolute)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-validation-engine

I am using [**Position Absolute's Validation Engine**](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) for validating values on form.

The issue is that on validation, the error prompts do not appear attached to the textboxes (input type:text) as they are expected. I know that the issue is with the margin-top that I have given to the textboxes but I cannot change that. Sample code snippet is provided here...

html:

```
<form id="frmTest" style="position:relative">
    <div id="divContents" style="position:relative; overflow-y:auto; overflow-x:none;">
        <div class="row1">
            <span>FName:</span>
            <input id="txtFName" data-prompt-position="bottomRight" class="validate[required] text-input" tabindex="1" />
        </div>
        <div class="row2">
            <span>LName:</span>
            <input id="txtLName" class="validate[required] text-input" tabindex="2" />
        </div>
        <div class="row3">
            <span>Age:</span>
            <input id="txtAge" class="validate[required, custom[integer],min[1]] text-input" tabindex="3" />
        </div>
    </div>

        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#frmTest').validationEngine();

$('#txtFName').focus();

$('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
    return $('#frmTest').validationEngine();
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NCB39/17/).

The divs that I have created are just sample but in live environment, they are collapsible divs. Also, I don't want to hard-code data-prompt-position value for each input field as there are more than 100 fields in each form. So am looking for a generic way of handling this issue (which I know is possible through CSS but don't know how?)

The demo setup having the issue is on [**www.x-lant.com**](http://www.x-lant.com)

Use **guest** / **pwd** to login to the application.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't reply to @Potherca . What, where, when, how?

Comment: @FelipeAls, I apologies but will provide link to my web-app that will provide the scenario specific to my issue, in sometime. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just used this code in js

```
$('#frmTest').validationEngine({promptPosition : "bottomRight"});
```

and this in css

```
.formError{margin-top: 15px!important;}
```

and it looks good.
The updated fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7zkgR/5/).

I hope this helps you.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>

    <form id="frmTest" style="position:relative">
        <div id="divContents" style="position:relative; overflow-y:auto; overflow-x:none;">
            <div class="row1">
                <span>FName:</span>
                <input id="txtFName" data-prompt-position="bottomRight" class="validate[required] text-input" tabindex="1" />
            </div>
            <div class="row2">
                <span>LName:</span>
                <input id="txtLName" class="validate[required] text-input" tabindex="2" />
            </div>
            <div class="row3">
                <span>Age:</span>
                <input id="txtAge" class="validate[required, custom[integer],min[1]] text-input" tabindex="3" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>​
```

**CSS**

```
body
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

div.row1, div.row2, div.row3
{
    min-height: 100px;
}

span
{
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 20px 5px 0 20px;
    width: 50px;
}

#txtFName, #txtLName, #txtAge
{
    margin-top: 20px;
}

input[type=text]
{
    width: 150px;
}
.formError{
    margin-top: 15px!important;
}
```

**​JS**

```
$('#frmTest').validationEngine({promptPosition : "bottomRight", autoPositionUpdate: true});

$('#txtFName').focus();

$('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
    return $('#frmTest').validationEngine();
});
​
```

Also, more documentation [here](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine).

Comment: Appreciate your reply. Your suggestion does works in some way but if I test in various resolutions, it fails. Can you suggest something more? Thank you again.

Comment: Can you describe more clearly how "it fails" and in which resolution(s)?

Comment: @Potherca, I apologies for the delay as I was quite busy with few urgent things. Now as for the issue if different resolution goes, the code on jsFiddle does work but I will post the link of my web application along with the guest user name and password. Request you to please test in various resolution and let me know what can be the resolution. Thank you again.

Comment: @Potherca, I have updated my question with link to demo site which is replica of our live application. Haven't made any changes as suggested by tsergium as I thought a fresh look at the problem might lead to correct solution. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for not posting until now, I edited my response, added code and a new fiddle. Please test it. I think this is what you are looking for: autoPositionUpdate: true; ... hope this time it works

Comment: @tsergium, You latest suggestion did work for my problem except that when the error prompts are displayed and a collapsed div is opened than the error prompts in the div below the recently expanded div were not updated in terms of their positions. But I was able to resolve that too by using "updatePromptsPosition" on expand and collapse events of div. Thank you very much for saving me from lot of headache. You do deserve the reward.

Answer (score 0):

Open jquery.validationEngine.js

and goto

```
// LEAK GLOBAL OPTIONS
    $.validationEngine = {
        fieldIdCounter: 0, defaults: {
// topRight, bottomLeft, centerRight, bottomRight, inline
promptPosition: "topLeft",
```

Set your Position